# 4 times "Undefined control sequence. \end{figure}" after each figure and table

Tags: errors, templates

I am using the [LaTeX template for writing bachelor, master, and seminar theses at the Chair for Information Systems and Information Management.](https://wiwi-gitlab.uni-muenster.de/lsis/isthesis). I have a problem with figures and tables, the following code snippet already causes trouble.

```
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Minimal example}
    \label{minexample}
    \begin{tabular}{*{4}{l}}
        \toprule
        ID    & Difference \\ \midrule
        1     & 10        \\
        2     & 7               
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

In this case it's obviously 4 times `Undefined control sequence. \end{table}`. The table is displayed as expected, but has one caption above with the correct text and one caption below, without any text. I'm guessing these are two different problems though.

I'm using texlive on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Works for me -- are you using `\usepackage{booktabs}`, by any chance? No? Then add it please!

Comment: I'm using a template which does indeed `\RequirePackage{booktabs}`. I don't know what it does, though, and whether it has anything to do with my problems.

Comment: Well, `booktabs` provides nice setups for `tabular` environments and especially the `\toprule` and `\midrule` commands. The problem with `templates` is: They are most times bad and you learn nothing by applying them

Comment: What you say about templates is true, in my experience. It's a (semi)professionally developed template from my university though, so complex, I barely understand it. I'm even pretty sure, it's correct. Could it be something with my texlive installation? Am I maybe missing packages? Seems unlikely to me, given that tabular and figures should be in the default installation.

Comment: Well, `semi`-professionally developed... ;-) From your given fragment hard to say. I've wrapped a small document around it and it worked for me (with `\usepackage{booktabs}`

Comment: Since it also happens with figures - and I'm sure I'm doing everything right there - I think it must be something with my setup. Either TeXstudio isn't configure correctly or something is wrong with my Texlive installation. Thanks anyway, for your support.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43380/discussion-between-juergen-and-christian-hupfer).

Comment: Well I would guess that your problems are related: your template probably redefines the floats to insert captions. But without the template it is impossible to debug your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that the template requires a special syntax, like so:

```
\begin{figure}[caption={Minimal example},label={minexample}]
   \begin{center}
      {\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{"minexamplefigure"}}
   \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Hopefully I can help, if anyone else runs into this problem. In case anyone knows, whether this is package or template specific, please let me know.

Comment: "the template requires" is unlikely to help anyone else so this barely qualifies as an answer unless you say what package is defining this.

Comment: [Here's a link](https://wiwi-gitlab.uni-muenster.de/lsis/isthesis/repository/archive.zip) to the template. Feel free to look into it. My guess is, that the template actually defines the syntax but it's too complicated for me to understand.

Comment: The template indeed defines that syntax, which isn't a good idea. But it has an example. Rule of thumb: If you change syntax that exists for more than 20 years, be sure you have your reasons and make the change apparent in the documentation.

Comment: You should not use the center environment, you should use `\centering`. On the other hand, something that takes up the full width of the line is centered by definition.

Comment: You should raise [an issue](https://wiwi-gitlab.uni-muenster.de/lsis/isthesis/issues) linking to this question here. It will help others in the future as well.

Comment: The example is how I found out about how to use the syntax. I couldn't understand the template, though, but it is what I have to use for my thesis. Unfortunately, for a lot of other issues there is no example. Figure and table side by side, where each has a main caption, for example. I can't create issues because I have no access to the gitlab. I contacted one of the authors of the template but he didn't know, either.